# How to assign different stylesheets in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have a stylesheet, `application.css` defined in `layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

However, there's a section of the site where the views will use a completely different stylesheet, `dashboard.css` which I've defined in its `index.html.erb`:

```
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dashboard" %>
..
```

Unless I remove the stylesheet_link_tag in the application layout file, there are conflicts which make the dashboard view weird. If I move the application layout stylesheet tag to a _header.html.erb partial which is rendered with every view in the non-dashboard section like below, it doesn't work. How must I call them?

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<header>
     <div id="headercontainer">
..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a separate layout for your dashboard, with specific stylesheets.

If you want customized stylesheet for one of your controllers (and all of its actions), it's quite easy to do. Create a layout with matching name, that is, for your `users_controller`, template name should be `users.html.erb`.

Also you can specify any layout for controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'some_layout'
end
```

If you want custom stylesheet only for some actions, specify corresponding layout in call to `render`.

```
def dashboard
  # some logic here
  render :layout => 'some_layout'
end
```

Comment: if you have, say, users_controller, define users.html.erb in layouts and rails will pick it up.

Comment: Or you can specify any layout in by calling `render` yourself `render :layout => 'my_layout'`

Comment: And lastly you can use `layout :dashboard` in your controller.

Comment: Sergei, this is also a good approach, and probably better for his implementation here.  I've used this in the past myself.  good answer!

Answer (score 6):

you should use a yield statement in your application.html.erb in the head element as such:

```
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

then in your view, you would use a content_for tag:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dashboard" %>
<% end %>
```

also read the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) on nested layouts. it'll teach you how to get fancy with this paradigm

Comment: This technique is really useful when each view can alter something in its layout (setting `title`, for example). In this case, @Simpleton just wants to use alternate stylesheet in one case. Do you think it's worth cluttering all the other views with reference to application.css?

Comment: well, i don't want to go and redo simpleton's site, but if we're talking about best practices. then the stylesheet in his application layout should be compatible with all views in the application. Then any layout specific code would go in the templates themselves.  setting it up this way would be a step towards doing it right

Comment: Another alternative would be an if / case statement in `application.html.erb` to choose the appropriate stylesheet via `params` - hope that makes sense to anyone reading this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define a second layout for dashboard (app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb). From that layout link to the dashboard stylesheets. Then use that layout from your dashboard views or controllers.

Oh just use some if conditions to link different stylesheets in the same layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag(dashboard_views? ? "dashboard" : "application") %>
```

Just implement dashboard_views? helper method to return true or false based on your views.

Comment: Why not make helper return stylesheet name then? `<%= stylesheet_link_tag get_stylesheet_name %>`

Oh, and you have unbalanced parens in your code :-)

Comment: good point. we can use many different ways here. I personally would use Chris' solution too. Thanks for the missing ')' problem I've fixed that. Red eye surfing here in Japan now ;-)